# Link with "-" in the URL using codeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, url

I am using Codeigniter (for the first time). I want to have the URL of a page "web-design", so it could be accessed like /web-design . I know it's impossible to make a class name with "-", so I have tried to make it possible using .htaccess, like this:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^web-design$ index.php/webdesign [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt|assets)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

but it's not working. It's giving me 404 error.
How can I make it work? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use routing in CI instead! That's why they made it.

This is actually pretty simple.

In `application/config/routes`.php add the following to the $route array:

```
$route['web-design'] = "webdesign";
$route['web-design/(:any)'] = "webdesign/$1";
```

Then you can create a controller called `Webdesign`; problem solved - the right way.
No need to extend anything or create other rewrite rules.

Comment: that's how I made it, but thanks for the answer anyway, it's the right one :)

Comment: By doing this, you would have to add routes for every url, you could end up with a mammoth sized routes file, and if you had to change the controller name you would need to remember to edit the routes. What is wrong with extending the router class? Add one file and it works from that point on.

Comment: @Rooneyl There's nothing wrong with extending the router class at all. IMO it seems overkill to extend the router class for a single URL (that's how I understood the question). If you need this as a basic functionality, your'e suggestion is easy to implement and it works like a charm.

Comment: Fair comment, I just always tend to do stuff to allow for the future. Single instances are few are far between, you always end up doing it again.

Comment: @Rooneyl I would agree with you on that - I actually think your solution should be basic functionality in CI as this could benefit other developers too.

Answer (score 2):

I use an extended Router class, which will convert any url with hyphens into underscores.

For example *www.mysite/web-design* will get routed to *web_design* or *www.mysite/home/whatever-you-want/2* will get routed to the *home* controller and run the *whatever_you_want* method/function, passing *2* as a parameter.

If you are using Codeigniter 2 put this in /application/core (and my sure that prefix is set to *MY_* in your config.

```
<?php if (! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
class MY_Router extends CI_Router {

    function set_class($class) {
        $this->class = str_replace('-', '_', $class);
    }

    function set_method($method) {
        $this->method = str_replace('-', '_', $method);
    }

    function _validate_request($segments) {
        // Does the requested controller exist in the root folder?
        if (file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).EXT)) {
            return $segments;
        }
        // Is the controller in a sub-folder?
        if (is_dir(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$segments[0])) {       
            // Set the directory and remove it from the segment array
            $this->set_directory($segments[0]);
            $segments = array_slice($segments, 1);

            if (count($segments) > 0) {
                // Does the requested controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().str_replace('-', '_', $segments[0]).EXT)) {
                    show_404($this->fetch_directory().$segments[0]);
                }
            } else {
                $this->set_class($this->default_controller);
                $this->set_method('index');

                // Does the default controller exist in the sub-folder?
                if ( ! file_exists(APPPATH.'controllers/'.$this->fetch_directory().$this->default_controller.EXT)) {
                    $this->directory = '';
                    return array();
                }

            }

            return $segments;
        }

        // Can't find the requested controller...
        show_404($segments[0]);
    }
}
```

Please note; this isn't my code but I can't remember where I found it, so if it is yours - kudos!

Answer (score 1):

`-` is a special character in regex. Try escaping it, like so:
 `RewriteRule ^web\-design$ index.php/webdesign [L]`

Comment: thanks for your help and for the fast reply. unfortunately it's not working :(

Comment: Are you adding anything after the web-design in the url? Even a / at the end will break it, because the $ after your web-design forces that `web-design` is the *end* of the string. Can you try if `RewriteRule ^web\-design index.php/webdesign [L]` works?

Comment: sorry it's my fault, it is working without the backslash, dont know why didnt it work before. Anyway thanks for your time!

Comment: UPDATE: it's working due to my routes.php file edit: $route['web-design'] = "webdesign"; I don't need the .htaccess rewriterule anymore